# How to stop global styles from affecting my component

Tags: angular

Is there a way to seal my Angular component off from the global style sheet? I don't want the styles in the global style sheet to take effect inside my component.

I have tried this

```
.reset {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

but is there not a different way?

Comment: there is no way to do this. global styles are global

Comment: You can, change encapsulation property in component decorator to ShadowDom. Added it in aan answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your component decorator, add:

```
@Component({
    selector: '..',
    templateUrl: '..',
    styleUrls: ['..'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom 
})
```

This will create a shadow dom and will force your component to use styles only from the provided styles/styleUrls array.

If you are using angular version < v6.1.0. You can use ViewEncapsulation.Native. It's deprecated after that.

Answer (score 2):

try this, it must work:

```
:host ::ng-deep .reset{

  //your style
}
```

Comment: how to use this further? should we have to add `.reset` class ?

Comment: incorrect. ng-deep only works though

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. The only way to achieve this is to override your rules defined in your global stylesheet in your component stylesheet.

Comment: how to override?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible because Angular provides a hierarchy for the stylesheets where the global style sheet is on top of everything.

However it is possible to exclude your component from this hierarchy by adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component's metadata, inside the decorator `@component`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class myComponent {
[...]
}
```

But in this way you excluded everything in that component from being affected from global style sheet.

Another approach would be set you rule as `!important` overriding any global rule

```
.reset {
  all: initial !important;
  * {
    all: unset !important;
  }
}
```

If I remember well you can workaround this problem even by defining a CSS id selector instead of CSS class, so it will be something like (not sure)

```
#reset {
  all: initial !important;
  * {
    all: unset !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to test an answer or potential answer prior to providing it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

add below code with reset class on starting of component template.

```
.reset {
* {
    all: unset !important;
}
}
```

Comment: do we need to apply `reset` class to any element? in my case it is ion-search

Comment: If you want to unset for an element, you can apply to it.```.ion-search{all: unset !important;}```

Answer (score 0):

By the name itself those styles are globally across all your components affected.That is the typical behavior of CSS, whenever it encounters an element, it applies all the defined css rules for that element.Anyway Angular components are view encapsulated, therefore with Angular's default view encapsulation strategy, you can override those styles in you component styles.